# how to get child properties in depth with javers and hibernate entities?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, javers

I am using Javers 5.5.2 on my client's project and the problem is the next:
I've got 2 entities: Vehicule and affectation. Affectation is the child of vehicule.

When I save and commit vehicule entity, i want Javers give me informations about affecation, but returns only the id of the affectation.

```java
/**
 * A Vehicule.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicule")
@Document(indexName = "vehicule")
public class Vehicule implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator 
 "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Z]$")
    @Column(name = "categorie_assurance")
    private String categorieAssurance;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("vehicules")
    private Affectation affectation;



**
 * A Affectation.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "affectation")
@Document(indexName = "affectation")
public class Affectation implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false)
    private String code;


    @Column(name = "commune", nullable = false)
    private String commune;


    @Column(name = "libelle", nullable = false)
    private String libelle;
```

Here is my endpoint to get audit from javers, I am using find changes.

```java
@RequestMapping("/vehicule/{id}/commits")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ChangesByCommitAndChanges>> getVehiculeChangesByCommit(@PathVariable Integer id,
                                                                                      @RequestParam Optional<String> param) {
        QueryBuilder jqlQuery = QueryBuilder
            .byInstanceId(id, Vehicule.class)
            .withNewObjectChanges(false)
            .withChildValueObjects()
            .limit(10);
        jqlQuery = param.isPresent() ? jqlQuery.withChangedProperty(param.get()) : jqlQuery;
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(groupChangesByCommit(javers.findChanges(jqlQuery.build())));
    }
```

This endpoint returns the following audits:

```java
Commit 17.0 done by LAURIE Adèle at 04 juin 2019, 09:17:01 :
* changes on nc.opt.refauto.domain.Vehicule/11700 :
  - 'affectation' reference changed from '...Affectation/7600' to '...Affectation/7900'
Commit 16.0 done by LAURIE Adèle at 04 juin 2019, 09:16:55 :
* changes on nc.opt.refauto.domain.Vehicule/11700 :
  - 'pret' reference changed from '' to '...Affectation/7700'
Commit 2.0 done by LAURIE Adèle at 03 juin 2019, 16:23:01 :
* changes on nc.opt.refauto.domain.Vehicule/11700 :
  - 'numeroCommande' value changed from '11-723' to '11-723aef'
  - 'numeroMarche' value changed from '250/10' to '250/10efae'
  - 'observations' value changed from 'efef' to 'efefefaef'
```

As you can see in theses logs, affectation returns only its Id and not others values of properties (code,commune,libelle).

Comment: Did you tried Shadows?

Comment: yes shadows dont return changes between old and update entity.

Comment: help ? please !

Comment: write me on https://gitter.im/bartoszwalacik